# Why addict the Jem'Hadar to Ketracel White?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-dominion

One of the few things that bothers me about the Dominion arc in Deep Space Nine is the Jem'Hadar. I enjoy the concept but I don't understand why they would be genetically addicted to Ketracel White (or anything else for that matter).

**There are some obvious problems**

- When they run out, the Jem'Hadar go ballistic and kill everything in sight uncontrollably.
- With the Gamma Quadrant and the supply of White cut off, Starfleet's first move was to go after 'White' production in the Alpha Quadrant. The Dominion may as well have put signs up saying "***this is our weak spot***."
- In Hippocratic Oath, Bashir and O'Brien meet a Jem'Hadar who was decanted **without the addiction**. As soon as a Jem'Hadar realizes that he doesn't need the White, he realizes he doesn't have to do what his Vorta tells him and it goes downhill from there.

Since The Dominion has already proven that it is capable of breeding loyal and obedient servants (The Vorta) then **why would they use an addiction that would open them up to such obvious liabilities instead of simply breeding the qualities they wanted into their soldiers?**

Comment: The example in _Hippocratic Oath_ a direct answer to this question:  The addiction is used to keep them loyal.  The one who was not addicted was a rare genetic anomaly, so it's not really a liability.

Comment: “Ignoring the social implications (which can be hard to do with DS9, especially Avery Brooks, sometimes)” — eh?

Comment: I've edited to remove some of the extraneous detail and focus the question a bit better. Feel free to press the rollback button if you liked it better before

Comment: The Vorta were uplifted from just-barely-sentience and bred/genetically manipulated for a *very* long time. The Jem'Hadar are a relatively recent creation.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: DS9 did a lot of social commentary and Avery Brooks wasn't quiet about his opinions. Memory Alpha says that, on the Jem'Hadar, Brooks "found analogies between the Jem'Hadar and young African-American men when Brooks directed "The Abandoned". Brooks commented: "for me, it was very much a story about young brown men, and, to some extent, a story about a society that is responsible for the creation of a generation of young men who are feared, who are addicted, who are potential killers."'

Comment: @JoeL.: I watched DS9 Very recently and I've read most of the info I can find on them. I haven't seen anything that suggests they are a recent addition to the Dominion. Do you have a source?

Comment: @geewhiz: It's implied though not stated. The Vorta believe they met and were uplifted by the Founders while the Founders were on the run, long before the Founders began to establish their empire. The Jem'Hadar were made later as muscle for the Dominion.

Comment: `The Dominion may as well have put signs up saying "this is our weak spot."`  Of course, the engineering of the Jem'Hadar occurred long before the Dominion even knew about the wormhole to the alpha quadrant.

Comment: @JoeL: It was said onscreen that the Dominion was approximately 2,000 years old. If what the Vorta are right about being "enhanced" prior to the Dominion's founding and the Jem'Hadar were created after that enhancement or after the founding itself, then the Jem'Hadar would be young compared to the Vorta. You can't say "recent" though without a timeframe to go by. The Jem'Hadar could have been created 2,000 years ago which would make them older than the Federation by a lot and even older than the Klingon Empire which hardly makes them recent.

Comment: @Michael: It's a weakness even in the Gamma Quadrant. If a Jem'Hadar ship is cut off from the Dominion and can't resupply, destroying its supply of Ketracel White would endanger the entire crew. If a sufficiently powerful military invaded Dominion Space in the Gamma Quadrant, 'White' production and storage facilities would be first strike priorities in order to cripple the Dominion military and planets on which the chemical building blocks of Ketracel White were present would be secondary targets. The war could be over in weeks.

Comment: @geewhiz: That's why I said *"relatively* recent", meaning relative to the Vorta.

Comment: @geewhiz: ah, gotcha.

Comment: @JoeL.: It also wasn't established that the Founders uplifted the Vorta and THEN created the Jem'Hadar, only that they uplifted the Vorta AND created the Jem'Hadar. It's entirely possible that they did both at the same time. The Weyoun clone said that the Vorta were uplifted to serve the Founders as a reward for helping the wounded Changeling but didn't say it happened immediately. It could be that the Changeling left the Vorta as they were and returned to modify the Vorta when they were ready to start the Dominion but knew they would need soldiers too so they made the Jem'hadar then too.

Comment: Isn't this like asking why humans are addicted to food and water?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Ketracel White is used to keep the Jem Hadar loyal to the founders as well as functioning as their sole source of food and drink. In the event that they become disloyal to the Founders (something that's apparently a rather more common occurrence than the Founders would like the Federation to believe) they can simply withdraw access to the substance and they'll all die.

> **BASHIR:** *I know that **the Jem'Hadar have been genetically engineered by the Dominion to be addicted to what you call
>   ketracel-white. And that by controlling the supply of the drug, the
>   Founders maintain control over you.***
>
> **GORAN'AGAR:** ***The Vorta. They are the ones who control the drug.*** They are the ones we came here to escape.
>
> **BASHIR:** *Escape? You're trying to leave the Dominion?*
>
> <sup><sub>[DS9 : Hippocratic Oath](http://anonymouse.org/cgi-bin/anon-www.cgi/http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/475.htm)</sub></sup>

and

> **SISKO:** *Couldn't the Founders just order them to surrender? From what I know, the Jem'Hadar have been genetically conditioned to obey
>   them.*
>
> **WEYOUN:** ***The Founders' ability to control the Jem'Hadar has been somewhat overstated. Otherwise we never would have had to addict them
>   to the white.***
>
> **SISKO:** *Sounds like the Dominion isn't quite as stable as you'd like us to believe.*
>
> <sup><sub>[DS9: To the Death](http://anonymouse.org/cgi-bin/anon-www.cgi/http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/496.htm)</sub></sup>

Comment: Has anyone considered the fact that, based on these quotes, it might not have been the Founders that created the addiction, but rather the Vorta?

Comment: @moo - Both the Vorta and the Jem'hadar are the products of genetic manipulation. It's possible (albeit highly unlikely) that the Jem'hadar were loyal to the Vorta first and were then co-opted by the Founders. I fail to see why you'd think that though.

Comment: I'm not saying the Jem'hadar were ever loyal to the Vorta at all, but given that the Founders seem to use the Vorta to run the Dominion at arms length, surely that also probably involves managing the Jem'hadar force, including updating the genetic code used to create them.  Perhaps at some point in the past, the Vorta decided they had had enough of rampaging, hard to control soldiers, so they did something about it, especially as they were more likely to suffer as a result of uncontrolled Jem'hadar than the Founders were.  It would be within their scope of being the Founders facilitators...

Comment: @moo - Ah, I see. That's wandering into the realms of fan-fiction though

Answer (score 15):

While Richard's answer is excellent, it overlooks one central point in Geewhiz's note.

> "When they run out, the Jem'Hadar go ballistic and kill everything in sight uncontrollably."

This is not actually a disadvantage, if accommodated or planned for.  Jem'Hadar have an incredibly short lifetime (see DS9: To the Death) and mature very quickly, going from infant to Fighting size in a matter of weeks (see DS9: The Abandoned).  Given this accelerated life, if a company is compromised from white withdrawal the following strategic points become important:

- The company will self-destruct in a short time frame (DS9: Rocks and Shoals)
- If members of the company are able to survive white withdrawal, they will have trouble subverting others (DS9: Hippocratic Oath)
- The company can be materially replaced quickly. (DS9: The Abandoned)
- Direct intervention by a Founder can probably accommodate the situation (Any DS9 showing Founder-Jem'Hadar Contact).
- The second, third and fourth items may be combined for an effective, if heartless solution to an insurrection

Given the Founders view all species as subservient, and have a very long term view of strategy, it does not seem that this apparent liability would be viewed as such by them.

Comment: Maybe the Jem'Hadars' concept of honor plays into this, too? We were shown on some occasions that they adhere to an honor codex that requires killing members of the own team under certain circumstances. When parts of a group of Jem'Hadar start becoming disloyal, it seems conceivable some members of the group may feel compelled to act as a "kill switch" for the entire group for reasons of honor, thereby accelerating point 1.

Answer (score 7):

breeding a loyal dog is not as easy as breeding an attack dog

fighters have to have the ability to think for themselves in tactical situations, an individual who thinks for himself can choose to disobey his master.

short answer they couldnt do it because breeding a loyal race would remove that races ability to think tactically and a soldier who cant think tactically is worthless

Answer (score 2):

Think of it this way.

1. You need my mother's lasagna to live.
2. Without it you will die
3. You live a long ways away from me
4. You don't like my representative that tells you what to do
5. I send the lasagna to him

Now despite you not liking the person I put in charge you need to obey him or you will die, because I only send the lasagna to him.

It ensures obedience to a chain of command especially when the top of the chain can't be everywhere.

The founders are few compared to the empire they control and those they subjugate, the vorta clones act as administrative and command authority, the jem'hadar as foot soldiers.   The white keeps the jem'hadar obedient to the volta and maintains the chain of command.

We see examples of how distance from the head authority can lead to strayful alliegences in our own history.  The smaller Christian faiths came from the catholic church but were the result of being thousands of miles from Rome and the Vatican, of course bishops and cardinals would visit these outlying parishes but as soon as they were gone the local leader would do things to benefit himself rather than the central authority.

In modern times large religious organizations have local authorities in place to keep all parishes/wards in line with the central message and global communications allow for a control that was lacking hundreds of years ago.

The dominion is tens of thousands of square light years so a system has to be put in place to maintain control.  The vorta arr also by their nature easier to genetically keep obedient because they are not imbued with agression.  Think when are you least in control of yourself, when you are angry, so the Jem'hadar even with genetic modifications to be obedient could act out in agression and then lead to a spiral of becoming uncontrollable.  Solution forget about the wayward soldier and it will die because your people control what it needs to live.

Answer (score 1):

The Vorta weren't just loyal to the founders, they revered the founders as gods. No need for a "safety switch" like a Ketracel White dependency. They don't factor into the logic behind the need to do so for the Jem'Hadar - bred to be the ultimate soldiers above all else, a safety switch is a necessity to ensure loyalty. And they really weren't exactly loyal to the founders so much as to the Vorta - the source of their Ketracel White.

Comment: The Jem'Hadar considered the Founders divine as well. They were just further removed from them for the most part. According to the Memory Alpha article: "Although the Jem'Hadar worshipped the Founders as gods, the vast majority of the Jem'Hadar had never actually seen a Founder, and some doubted that they even existed." http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Jem%27Hadar 

That and the quote in Richard's answer indicates the problem is keeping the Jem'Hadar obedient to the Vorta.